# Custom UIView resize according to content

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, autolayout, intrinsic-content-size

I have a UITableview which needs to displays content(Image and text) based on the size of the image. (full width - height according to aspect ratio)

I have defined a custom cell and embedded Customview inside it.

Customview(It has imageview constrained to fit the Customview).

CustomView receives the image size from api. I calculate the height needed for Customview.

I have tried setting intrinsicContentSize of Customview according to size received of the image
As well as setting height constraint of the image.

But Height of the container does not reflect in UITableViewAutomaticDimension tableview.

However if set the height of the CustomView inside the cell it works.

Whats the best way to accomplish a custom view which signals the superview the height it needs to display?

Eg - http://ioscake.com/proper-usage-of-intrinsiccontentsize-and-sizethatfits-on-uiview-subclass-with-autolayout.html

Comment: help full answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/41650211/3752143

Comment: I need to design a view which can self size itself on placing it in cell. The view can updates its content based on the model and cell should resize according to it.